# Two keyboards stopped writing

Tags: keyboard

My wife has been using Acer desktop (Win 10) and keyboard for the past 6 years. She switches keyboard language from English to Norwegian and back without problems, using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (I am not sure of the exact combination she uses). This has never been a problem until last week when suddenly the keyboard stopped writing (the mouse works fine).
Tried her keyboard on my computer; it did not write. I lent her my keyboard so she could finish some
important business while I could find solutions on line. Within a day she did the same to my keyboard, it stopped writing. She has no idea what keystroke is causing it. In the meantime, I tried all the Internet suggestions (uninstall keyboard and restart computer; press <kbd>Shift</kbd> key for 8 seconds..etc.); nothing worked.
Any new ideas or suggestions out there?

Comment: What is "stopped writing"? Do any of the keys work? Are the keyboards even recognized?

Comment: No, non of the keys work. You press any key, as many times or as hard, nothing happens on the screen nor any action happens when you press Enter. It is shooting blanks.